# Turn off Twig cache

Tags: theming, 8, caching

I did [Disable Drupal 8 caching during development](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914) step by step ( also **finally rebuild the cache**) but yet my changes in `twig` files not take effects without rebuild the cache.

**sites/default/services.yml :**

```
parameters:
    session.storage.options: { gc_probability: 1, gc_divisor: 100, gc_maxlifetime: 200000, cookie_lifetime: 2000000 }
    twig.config: { debug: true, auto_reload: true, cache: false }
```

**sites/default/settings.php :**

```
 if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
   include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
 }
```

**sites/default/settings.local.php :**

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
```

**sites/development.services.yml :**

```
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

Where is the Problem?

Comment: did you restart apache after making changes?

Comment: @NoSssweat everything seems Ok,after your comment I try that but no achievement .

Comment: in **sites/default/settings.local.php** uncomment the `$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';` line

Comment: @NoSssweat I found my solution with ` $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
 $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';` .
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I resolved my problem by following lines in settings.local.php.

```
# $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

duplicate the line  and enable it  (by remove # before it)  and change `render` to `dynamic_page_cache` 
I mean the following line resolved your issue

```
 $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

in `Drupal >= 8.8` use

```
  $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.memory';
```

Comment: `$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.memory';` Works for drupal 8.7.3 too

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8.8 adding this to sites/default/settings.local.php worked for me:

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.memory';
```

For some reasons when I try to add it as recommended ('cache.backend.**null**') I have the following error

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service &quot;cache.backend.null&quot;. Did you mean one of these: &quot;cache.backend.apcu&quot;, &quot;cache.backend.memory&quot;, &quot;cache.backend.php&quot;?
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling for configuring caching for Drupal 8, the following steps resolve the issue.

- Copy the example.settings.local.php which is located outside of the files folder into files folder with settings.local.php
- Uncomment `$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';`
- Uncomment `$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';` too

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a **SUPER EASY** way to do this. Install the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module, and toggle the **Enable development mode** checkbox to **turn off/on twig cache and other caches with just a click**. No need to edit settings.php and *services.yml files back and forth.