# Disable the cache for a specific view

Tags: views, 8, theming, caching

I'm showing my users a random number (`{{ random() }}`) in a twig which is being rendered in a view. But when I refresh a page it just shows me the same number.

I tried several things but they all failed:

1. Disabled caching in `admin/config/development/performance`
2. Disabled cache in views advanced settings
3. tried to use [cacheexclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module
4. I even disabled twig cache!

How can I completely disable cache for specefic twig or specefic view?

**Update:**

By the way in response header there is a header called `x-drupal-cache:HIT`. (It's `MISS` for the first time and then `HIT` after first load) Why?

**Update 2:**
I uninstalled `Internal Page Cache` too. the `x-drupal-cache` is gone now but the page is still being cached! I literally disabled everything but still no luck to show a random number in twig in a view..

This is my response header if it helps:

```
cache-control:must-revalidate, no-cache, private
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Wed, 28 Feb 2018 14:26:47 GMT
expires:Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
server:nginx
status:200
strict-transport-security:max-age=15768000
vary:Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-drupal-dynamic-cache:UNCACHEABLE
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-generator:Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
x-ua-compatible:IE=edge
```

**Solution:**

I uninstalled Internal Cache module and ALSI [big pipe](https://www.drupal.org/project/big_pipe) module too.

Comment: 1 and 2 should be enough ... maybe your server is running some kind of cache ? its been know with some very popular hosts to run cache for an account automatically and you have to actually go in the panel to disable it.

Comment: @GiorgosK I'm just using Nginx and php-fpm and nothing else... In response header there is a tag called `x-drupal-cache:HIT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately point 1 doesn't work for anonymous traffic.

You have to uninstall the Internal Page Cache module.

Or trigger

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

in a view hook.

When the View is placed on most or all pages then uninstall the Internal Page Cache, because the page cache kill switch also disables the dynamic page cache and you don't want to disable both caches, unless this is only for a few pages which don't have too much traffic.

Additionally you need point 2 (disabled cache in views advanced settings) in any case.

**Update:**

> By the way in response header there is a header called
>   x-drupal-cache:HIT. (It's MISS for the first time and then HIT after
>   first load) Why?

This header is generated by the Internal Page Cache, a HIT means it is served from this cache.

Comment: @4x4 are you sure ?  I have at least a view on Drupal 3.7 currently that serves random content from a view (even for anonymous) with internal Page Cache enabled as I described in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I add `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();`? `mytheme_views`?

Comment: @GiorgosK, yes, see this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2352009. Sky, you can use any view hook, but I would prefer `hook_views_pre_render`, because this also works in themes.

Comment: @4k4 I disabled Internal Page Cache Module. Also added `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` too. The `x-drupal-cache` header is gone but the page is still being cached :( I just did everything!

Comment: @Sky, to be sure you can add `$variables['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];` to hook_preprocess_views_view, although this should be done already by point 2 in Views UI. I don't know what you can else do, at least not with the information you've provided so far.

Comment: ... for example if `{{ random() }}` was inside of an entity template, then you would need to add cache max-age = 0 to the preprocess hook of that entity, for example hook_preprocess_node

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to uninstal big pipe module too

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 in order to disable cache for a specific view

```
your view > ADVANCED > Caching > None
```

For your case twig caching is probably at play but it better be left untouched.

```
services.yml > twig.config:  cache: false
```

You might want to consider creating a random number in view using 
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_random_seed

**NOTE:** If you Drupal cache is enabled in `admin/config/development/performance` than the `no cache` setting of any view will not be respected by default and all views will be cached instead.  Installing [cache_control_override](https://www.drupal.org/project/cache_control_override) will help resolve this and allow views configured with `no cache` to work as such.  Read more on this problem in the module's page.

Above problem is resolved assuming there is no other caching mechanisms between the drupal site and the browser.

Comment: Thank you but I disabled twig cache too but it loads the same number after the first page load (After clear cache)

Comment: Try rebuilding cache https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203184/turn-off-twig-cache.  Also just realized that there is a report that the clearing of twig cache is not that reliable https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2752961